# DateTimePicker Validation Submit Actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am spending my time programming and designing a website that uses MVC, .NET, jQuery, and `DateTimePicker`. The problem is that the next and previous arrow month navigation of the jquery datetimepicker calendar and additional JavaScript allow submitting future orders outside `DateTimePicker` min and max date options. The calendar correctly creates 3 months of dates selectable from today and 3 months into the future.

Is there any way to check the month and year navigation of the jquery selector `getValue` property and example in the code below for ajax post submission?  Some of the steps include a function that returns a true or false value and later on completes a JavaScript jQuery AJAX submission for order.  The goal is to limit navigation of the calendar min and max date.

I have tried changing the `numberOfMonths`, `showCurrentAtPos`, `numberOfMonths`, and `showOtherMonths` options to fix the selected date from jquery selector getValue. Currently the calendar allows arrow (prev/next) navigation, I would like to limit this, the options mentioned above do not fix this order submission.  I have attempted accessing `DateTimePicker` date-selectable properties without much success, such as visible. I have tried disabling next and previous arrow navigation, still not sure about drop down month and year select.

```
// getting calendar selected day within javascript submit and post function
var CurrentlySelectedDate = $('#txtFeatureDelivery').datetimepicker('getValue');

    //a constant aTime for easier datetimepicker creation
    var aTime = [], minTime = 9, maxTime = 21;
    for (var i = minTime; i <= maxTime; i++) {
        var tm = ""; var ap = "AM";
        if (i < 10) { tm = "0" + i; }
        else if (i < 12) { tm = "" + i; }
        else if (i == 12) { tm = "" + i; ap = "PM"; }
        else { tm = "" + (i - 12); ap = "PM"; }

        aTime[aTime.length] = tm + ":00 " + ap;
        if (i != maxTime) {
            aTime[aTime.length] = tm + ":30 " + ap;
        }
    }


var sdt = new Date();
sdt.setDate(sdt.getDate() + 1);
sdt.setHours(9);
sdt.setMinutes(30);
sdt.setSeconds(0);
sdt.setMilliseconds(0);

var mdt = new Date();
mdt.setMonth(mdt.getMonth() + 3);

$('#txtFeatureDelivery').datetimepicker({
    allowTimes: aTime,
    todayButton: false,
    format: 'm/d/Y h:i A',
    formatTime: 'h:i A',
    //stepMonths: 3,
    step: 30,
    minDate: '+1970/01/01',
    maxDate: mdt,
    inline: true,
    startDate: sdt
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showCurrentAtPos: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true
});
```

Comment: I don't see `getVal` anywhere, did you mean `getValue` ?

Comment: It also looks like you're missing some commas in the object you're passing to dateTimePicker, are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Hi Bryan made the suggested change to the code above, I have been copy pasting code and commenting it around stackoverflow, difficult to keep edited in a  nice, readable, and useable format .  In the code I am using numberOfMonths was used once.

Comment: What are you using for `datetimepicker`? A plugin? This problem is hard to reproduce without the full code.

Comment: Hi Brian, looking through the code comments that I have I'm using, it looks like a wrapper Kartik Visweswaran, Krajee.com, version 1.3.4 datetimepicker is used and built on  jQuery DateTimePicker plugin v2.5.4 * homepage http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
 * author Chupurnov Valeriy (<chupurnov@gmail.com>).